# How to call my prepared statement to pull the article with the specific ID from the database?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

```
    public static final String TABLE_ARTICLE = "Article";
    public static final String COLUMN_ARTICLE_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_ARTICLE_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_ARTICLE_CONTENT = "content";
    public static final String COLUMN_ARTICLE_CREATION_DATE = "creationDate";
    public static final String COLUMN_ARTICLE_EXPIRE_DATE = "expireDate";
    public static final String COLUMN_ARTICLE_LAST_EDIT = "lastEdit";
    public static final String COLUMN_ARTICLE_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String COLUMN_ARTICLE_TOPIC = "topic";
    public static final String COLUMN_ARTICLE_AUTHOR_ID = "authorId";
    public static final String COLUMN_ARTICLE_PUBLISHER_ID= "publisherId";
    public static final String COLUMN_ARTICLE_PUBLISHER_COMMENT= "publisherComment";
    public static final int INDEX_TABLE_ARTICLE = 1;
    public static final int INDEX_ARTICLE_ID = 2;
    public static final int INDEX_ARTICLE_TITLE = 3;
    public static final int INDEX_ARTICLE_CONTENT = 4;
    public static final int INDEX_ARTICLE_CREATION_DATE = 5;
    public static final int INDEX_ARTICLE_EXPIRE_DATE = 6;
    public static final int INDEX_ARTICLE_LAST_EDIT = 7;
    public static final int INDEX_ARTICLE_STATUS = 8;
    public static final int INDEX_ARTICLE_TOPIC = 9;
    public static final int INDEX_ARTICLE_AUTHOR_ID = 10;
    public static final int INDEX_ARTICLE_PUBLISHER_ID = 11;
    public static final int INDEX_ARTICLE_PUBLISHER_COMMENT = 12;

public static final String LOAD_ARTICLE = "SELECT " + COLUMN_ARTICLE_TOPIC + ", " + COLUMN_ARTICLE_TITLE + ", " +
    COLUMN_ARTICLE_CONTENT + ", " + COLUMN_ARTICLE_PUBLISHER_COMMENT + ", " + COLUMN_ARTICLE_EXPIRE_DATE + " FROM " + TABLE_ARTICLE +
            " WHERE " + COLUMN_ARTICLE_ID + " = ?";

private PreparedStatement DBLoadArticle;
```

Here I have initialized the tables and the prepared statement.
The database is also already set up.

```
public Article DBLoadArticle(int id) {
        try {
            Article article = DBLoadArticle. 



            if (article == null) {
                throw new SQLException("Couldn't get Article!");
            } else
                System.out.println("Article successfully loaded!");

            return article;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't get Article: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

How do I create this method ? I do not know if I should use a ResultSet or another query, but I want to use my prepared statement to pull it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a DB connection and that you have an initialized prepared statement from your connection, the next step would probably be to populate any parameters (the '?' in your query), execute the statement and then parse the output.

(I changed the PreparedStatement object name to begin with lower case.)

```
dbLoadArticle.setInt(1, id); // Set the ID
dbLoadArticle.execute(); // Run the statement
ResultSet rs = dbLoadArticle.getResultSet(); // Get the result set
article = null; // Initialize
if(rs.next()) {
    // Found something! Map the Article
    article = new Article(
        rs.getString(1),
        rs.getString(2),
        ...
    );
}
// Possibly check for multiple hits?
rs.close(); // Don't forget to close
dbLoadArticle.close(); // and close
```

Comment: Thank you ! Somehow my brain thought setting the int would change the initial id. Now I get it !